# subprocess.run isn't working while using pyinstaller with --noconsole --onefile

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using Pyinstaller 3.6, Python 3.8.3 and when I'm compiling this code ( using flag --onefile ):

```
import subprocess

try:
    output = subprocess.run('dir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    toWrite = output.stdout.decode('ansi')

    f = open('output.txt', 'w')
    f.write(toWrite)
    f.close()
except Exception as e:
    f = open('output.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(e))
    f.close()

exit(0)
```

everything works fine. Here's the output.txt file:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.

 Volume Serial Number is E612-C89D

 Directory of C:\Users\trolo\OneDrive\Desktop\progs\tests\dist

14.07.2020  12:11    <DIR>          .
14.07.2020  12:11    <DIR>          ..
14.07.2020  11:58         9я777я078 test3.exe

               1 File(s)      9я777я078 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  12я544я409я600 bytes free
```

But when I'm adding flag `--noconsole`, I'm getting this in the output.txt file:

```
[WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

What is wrong, how can make it work without showing console window ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python 3:  you can simply pass stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL

```
subprocess.Popen( args=[self.exec_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Python 2.x: you need to get a filehandler to null, then pass that to popen

```
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
subprocess.Popen( args=[self.exec_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=devnull)
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, people going through this issue needs to know this....this is amazing